# Headphones aren't working on S7

Tags: headphones, hardware, headphone-jack

I have an S7 Active, and all of suddenly both my headphones stopped working with it. The interesting part is my headset I was for my Xbox works with it, and my headphones work with everything else I tried them on. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try pressy? it maybe blocked the sound! if not, call google to help.  if it does not help, get a new phone.  lastly, they are not compatible. if one of these do not work, comment and ill try to fix it.